# assigning a variable for a dataframe in a for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a model I need to run multiple times in a loop where the only thing that changes is one term (in this simplified example) in the name of a dataframe.

I want to change that term each loop in order to call a new dataframe, this is what I have:

```
X_df<-cbind(1,2,3)
Y_df<-cbind(4,5,6)

VAR <- c("X", "Y")

for(n in VAR){

    ##Set Variables
    V1=paste(n,"_df",sep="")
}
```

However, when I do this, on the first loop V1 is simply the text "X_df". How do I get V1 to be the dataframe 1,2,3 on the first loop and 4,5,6 on the second loop?

I tried to use assign but this does seem to do what I want. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() will do the job

```
X_df<-cbind(1,2,3)
Y_df<-cbind(4,5,6)

VAR <- c("X", "Y")

for(n in VAR){
   #Set Variables
   V1=get(paste(n,"_df",sep=""))
   print(V1)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I knew I was missing something simple - staring at the problem too long. Thanks.